# UILabel doesn't show up in the debug view hierarchy

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, xcode8

For testing purpose, I'm checking whether the `UILabel` is exist or not in the view hierarchy. But, the `UILabel` doesn't show up in the debug view hierarchy, if the `UILabel` text is not set. Any help?

Comment: Add your screen images.

Comment: Give a background color to the label and check.

Answer (score 1):

Probably because it will have dimensions of 0x0 and it is useless on the view. You could set it to a set width and height with constraints, or just put some whitespace in it to give the effect of it being empty.